# How does one make jQuery animate-show a hidden element smoothly?

Tags: jquery

I've noticed that when I try to animate an element which is originally hidden into view there's no animation - the element just appears immediately.

Try the following code, for example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      span {white-space: nowrap; display: none}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function hide() {
        $("span").animate({width: "hide"}, 2000);
      }
      function show() {
        $("span").animate({width: "show"}, 2000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>This is a span.</span>
    <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
    <button onclick="show()">show</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `span` element is hidden at first, because of the CSS. `show()`-ing it makes it simply appear, immediately, even though I'm asking for a 2-second animation. (`hide()`-ing it works smoothly.)

How can I make it `show()` smoothly too?

While at it, I've noticed another issue as well: while the animation is taking place the vertical location of the elements changes a little (if you look closely you'll see the buttons a little lower and the span a little higher during the animation). Why is that, and how can it be prevented?

By the way I'm using `width` in this example, but the same happens for `height`. I'm using Firefox 4.

Edit: having read the answers given so far I would like to emphasise that the problem is only when the element is originally hidden by the CSS - otherwise the above code works perfectly fine. Also, I'm not interested in all kinds of other animations (like jQuery's own `show()` or an `opacity` animation) - I want my own animation (like `width` in my example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a bug in jQuery. Before jQuery starts showing the element it doesn't set `display: inline-block`. So it stays `display: inline` and elements with that style don't "respond" to width/height changes. So it isn't animated. Before hiding it is set properly so it is animated.

I managed to work-around it by setting style to something like that:

```
span {white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;}
.span {display: none;}
```

and html:

```
<span class="span">This is a span.</span>
<div style="display:inline-block; overflow: hidden;">
    <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
    <button onclick="show()">show</button>
</div>
```

<strike>Edit: I think that buttons are changing their position because of setting `span` element `display` style to `inline-block`.</strike>

Edit2: Another workaround is not using `span` but some block element.

Edit3: To prevent changing buttons position you need to wrap them in `span` (or other allowed html tag) that have set the same `display` and `overflow` styles like the `span` element during animation. That is `display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;`. I edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, Beniamin! Setting it to inline-block works :) About the position change, is there a way to prevent it? This damages the visual aspect of my site.

Comment: Edited answer to address the position change.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's own show() and hide(). You can specify a duration for those.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: I'm not using jQuery's own `show()` and `hide()` because I want my own custom animation (for example animating the `width` property). In any case, the same problem is there also when using those (they animate over a few properties; some of them run smoothly, but some do not). I emphasise that the problem is only when the element is originally hidden by the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`.show('slow')` and `.hide('slow')`

or try

`.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`

the other thing you could do is set the opacity to 0.0 and then show a hidden element. after that you animate the opacity to 1.0 to fade the element in.

Comment: `width` and `height` CAN be given the propertis `'hide'` and `'show'`. And that works perfectly fine, usually. I emphasise that the problem is only when the element is originally hidden by the CSS.

Comment: Don't forget `.slideDown([duration])` and `.slideUp([duration])`.